# Opengl Setting image coordinates with glTexCoord2f

Tags: c++, opengl

Im working on a project in opengl c++. Im trying to create a skybox and i 've been able to create all the 4 faces with the right textures with the right image coordinates. But i'm having a problem at the upper face.I can't set properly the image coordinates. This is the code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS); // back
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-size , height , -size);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( size , height , -size);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( size , -17.00f , -size);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-size , -17.00f , -size);
glEnd();

//left
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skytexture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-size , height , -size);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-size , height ,  size);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-size , -17.00f , size);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-size , -17.00f ,-size);
glEnd();

 //front
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , skytexture[3]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f);glVertex3f( size  , height , size);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f);glVertex3f( -size , height , size);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f);glVertex3f( -size , -17.0f ,  size);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f);glVertex3f(size ,   -17.0f , size);
glEnd();


//right
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skytexture[2]);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(size , height , -size);
 glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f); glVertex3f(size , height ,  size);
 glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(size , -17.00f , size);
 glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f); glVertex3f(size , -17.00f ,-size);
 glEnd();
```

**//------ HERE IS THE PROBLEM WITH SETTING THE COORDINATES**
**//------ THE RESULT IS MESSED UP**

```
 //up
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , skytexture[4]);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 0.0f);glVertex3f(-size , height , -size);
 glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 0.0f);glVertex3f( size , height , -size);
 glTexCoord2f(1.0f , 1.0f);glVertex3f( size , height , size);
 glTexCoord2f(0.0f , 1.0f);glVertex3f(-size , height , size);
 glEnd();
```

Comment: How does the result look? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Well it's clear but it's not positioned the way it is supposed to.  All of the 4 textures of the wall s are placed corectly .But the upper side is not

Comment: i tried a few combinations of the texture tex coordinates but they wont work